# How to solve this problem of Memory error?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

So I have this error message that ruins all the fun with my work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python36\Scripts\Masterarbeit-1308\CNN - Kopie.py", line 97, in <module>
    model.fit(np.asarray(X_train), np.asarray(Y_train), batch_size=32, epochs=100, verbose=1, validation_data=(np.asarray(X_test), np.asarray(Y_test)))
  File "C:\Users\\****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 492, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
MemoryError
```

Does anyone has a solution for this?
I work on a machine i7 7th generation with 16 GB RAM.

To explain more, That's my code, It take al list of arrays (.npy) converted from sounds spectograms to .npy and saved in Input-CNN:

```
import os, numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, Dropout, Dense
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from keras.utils import to_categorical

folder = 'D:\InputCNN - Copie'
folder1 = 'C:\Python\Python36\Scripts\Masterarbeit-1308\Data'
from keras import backend as K


My_Data = os.listdir(folder)
num_data= len(My_Data)
Classnames = os.listdir(folder1)
class_num = len(Classnames)
arr =[np.load(os.path.join(folder, filename), fix_imports=True) for filename in os.listdir(folder)]

labels = np.ones((num_data,))
labels[0:31]= 0
labels[31:80] = 1
labels[80:128] = 2
labels[128:131] = 3
labels[131:143] = 4
labels[143:157] = 5
labels[157:209] = 6
labels[209:] = 7
Y = to_categorical(labels,class_num)
x, y = shuffle(arr, Y, random_state=2)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(My_Data)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(x, Y, test_size=0.2)
##
def build_model(idx,X,Y,nb_classes):
    K.set_image_data_format('channels_last')   
    nb_filters = 64  # number of convolutional filters to use
    pool_size = (2, 2)  # size of pooling area for max pooling
    kernel_size = (3, 3)  # convolution kernel size
    nb_layers = 4
    input_shape = (X[idx].shape[1], X[idx].shape[2], X[idx].shape[3])

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(nb_filters, kernel_size, padding='valid', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=1))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))

    for layer in range(nb_layers-1):
        model.add(Conv2D(nb_filters, kernel_size, padding='valid', input_shape=input_shape))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=1))
        model.add(Activation('relu')) 
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128))

    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.6))
    model.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation='sigmoid'))
    return model

for idx in range(len(X_train)-1):
 model = build_model(idx,X_train,Y_train, class_num)

model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adadelta',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(np.array(X_train), np.array(Y_train), batch_size=8, epochs=100, verbose=1, validation_data=(np.array(X_test), np.array(Y_test))) #Here I have the problem
score = model.evaluate(np.array(X_test), np.array(Y_test), verbose=0)
print('Test score:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

The model fit function is the problem in my code, that should train my preconfigured model and returns an history object (A record of the training). I tried np.array and np.asarray and I got the same error message. 
If someone think that the model`s summary can be helpful, I'll post it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The problem is always by np.asarray or np.array. The problem still occurs. X_train, Y_train, X_test and Y_test is a list of arrays.

Comment: The problem comes only while converting X_train and Y_train from list to array  (they are a list of 174 arrays}. I don't have this problem with X_test (List of 44 arrays). 
The problem comes only if I want to convert a big list of data to array.

Comment: How big are each of the arrays in the lists that you are converting? Do your collections potentially include circular references, which could mean you are attempting to create an infinite number of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. Actually I changed the **shape of my data** in the list "X_train"  (from (218,128,740,1) to (128,740,1)). 
I found that, thanks to Keras, it will add automatically another axis with the number of my data injected to the network, and np.asarray works well even with more data.